Django-React App not finding manifest.json file
I am working on a Django + React powered system. I have encountered this manifest not found error for a while now. The frontend page shows nothing at all. Help me find the root cause.
I have shared the images as follows:
1.) The image of the error:

2.) Image of the admin page (working perfectly):

Any help will really be appreciated. Here is the link to my github where the files are: https://github.com/FelixOmollo/FourthYearProject
Here is my navbar code:
import AuthContext from '../context/AuthContext'
import {useContext} from 'react'
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";




import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

function Navbar() {

  const {user, logoutUser} = useContext(AuthContext)
  const token = localStorage.getItem("authTokens")

  if (token){
    const decoded = jwt_decode(token) 
    var user_id = decoded.user_id
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <Navbar.Brand href='/'>SPORRMS</Navbar.Brand>
          </a>

          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/s">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <Link class="nav-link" to="/about">About</Link>
              </li>
              {token === null && 
              <>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <Link class="nav-link" to="/login">Login</Link>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <Link class="nav-link" to="/register">Register</Link>
                </li>
              </>
              }

            {token !== null && 
              <>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" onClick={logoutUser} style={{cursor:"pointer"}}>Logout</a>
                </li>
              </>
              }   
              
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Navbar


Thanks in advance.
I was expecting the frontend to load normal. I was before bur after adding the auth to validate logins and signups. It stopped working. When I remove the auth and validations of the latter. It loads perfectly well.

Why you don't use normal django folder formattings? No template folder, no static folder. It obvious you don't have any url pattern reaching those files.

Also, why would we need your navibar code in this question? Have some respect. Post the question correctly.

Problem :-
Your settings.py
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'frontend/build'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]


STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'frontend/build/static'),
]


From index.html

      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->

Yes you have href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json, but how does django reach this public url?
Django won't serve static other places than frontend/build/static'.
Answer :-

use django static folder (frontend/build/static' and move manifest to it and use django static template tag to serve it. (eazy)

Or

write specific url in urls.py for manifest file. (hard)

